# Rails, carrierwave, and adding a username to a file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, carrierwave

How do I read the current user in a carrierwave uploader? Essentially, in WhateverUploader.rb I have -

```
def store_path(for_file = filename)
    "uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore.pluralize}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}/#{for_file}"
end
```

... and I'd like to put in something like

```
.../#{current_user.username}/...
```

I'm using Devise, but current_user does not seem to be available in the uploader. Would it be rational to do something like

```
.../#{User.find(Book.find(Chapter.find(model.id).book_id).user_id).username}/...
```

or am I being nuts? It works fine, but does not seem like it's optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using this -

```
  def store_dir

    #path will be user_id-username/book_id-title/Assets/filename.ext

    user_id = Book.find_by_id(model.id).user_id
    username = User.find_by_id(user_id).username
    book_id = model.id
    title = Book.find_by_id(book_id).title

    return "uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{user_id}-#{username}/#{book_id}-#{title}/Assets/"
  end
```

... as it seems easier to break the path down into components then combine them again in a path.